# How to apply a patch from Git in order to resolve an unfixed issue?

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, joomla-3.4, github, git

I have the latest stable build of Joomla installed, 3.4 at time of writing this.

The issue is that I get an error when trying to install zipped extension files.

> No file selected. Unable to find install package

I have found this link which supplies a patch for the issue. https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Extension_won%27t_install

Previously I did not have the website setup in git, but I have since created a git in my client (Tower) for the website. I have tried to install the patch by downloading the file as 6180.patch then apply patch through the client but this fails to complete.

Is there something else I can do to be able to upload extension zips?

Comment: Be sure that you're applying the patch correctly. I would suggest looking here instead: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/6180/files

Comment: How would you recommend to apply this patch to my files without manually editing them ?

Comment: Have a look at the following: https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/ but to be honest, there's nothing wrong with applying this patch manually by editing the files as it will be released in Joomla 3.4.1 anyway. There are only 3 files you really need to edit

Comment: Thanks, what I ended up doing was copying the raw files for the patch and then uploading them which did the trick. If you submit your first reference as an answer I can accept it. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are applying the patch incorrectly.

To properly install git patches, you will need to perform a few command line functions which are explain in the following tutorial:

https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/

Personally I think you could simply perform the change manually as there are only minor tweaks required in 3 files. To see the code difference, have a look at the pull request submitted to Joomla on Github:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/6180/files

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool mostly designed for testing purposes under Joomla: [com_patchtester](https://docs.joomla.org/Component_Patchtester_for_Testers)

You can directly search after the Pull Request id: 6180.